# hsts, 301s http www to https:// canonical htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, hsts

Comment 1: I'm new to stackoverflow, I'm not really a programmer, so please forgive me if I'm doing this wrong. (I'm very much yelling "dammit Jim, I'm a doctor not a coder!" right now)

Comment 2: I have tried to do my homework, but insofar as I am not a programmer, I have had some trouble figuring out the exact answer to my question. If I've missed something, please let me know, and hopefully this isn't a waste of anyone's time.

The ultimate goal is to speed up and secure my website. It should all go over https.

I had noticed that my (wordpress) website speed testing was much faster (load time=1-2s vs 5-8s) if I typed "https://" directly into the tester. The waterfalls indicate that it takes a long time to get the http redirect to https (which makes sense since there's currently no redirect listed in my .htaccess at all ... I'm surprised it doesn't fail entirely).

I'm hoping by providing redirects in the .htaccess, my site speed will be closer to what I see when typing in "https://" directly.

---

That all led me to investigate HSTS and 301 redirects in .htaccess. There seem to be a LOT of different ways of doing these redirects, and I'm not sure what the differences are.

For instance, is this better:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond !{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]

</IfModule>
```

or this (recommended by my hosting provider)?

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

---

Then I found on varvy the code for .htaccess `https://varvy.com/pagespeed/hsts.html`.

and I would like to add to .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=10886400; includeSubDomains;"
</IfModule>
```

(not preload right now) but I'm not sure if this should be inserted above or below the redirects.

And should I use `env=https` to prevent any attempt to send the HSTS over http?

To complicate further, [this article](http://sentinelstand.com/article/http-strict-transport-security-hsts-canonical-www-redirects) seems to indicate that I should have multiple redirects to make the the whole thing work correctly in all scenarios. The article makes sense to me, as does his proposed redirect scheme:

> http:// example.com → https:// example.com*
>   http:// www.example.com → https:// www.example.com* → https:// example.com*
>   https:// www.example.com → https:// example.com*

But I'm not sure how to implement something like that in the actual .htaccess and I'm a bit nervous about just trying stuff blindly.

Lastly, my various wordpress plugins have added a bunch of caching/security stuff to the .htaccess file. Do the redirects go above or below all of that?

my canonical (and ssl certificate) is at `https://example.com`, so I'd like all redirects to end up there (but preserving the remaining slugs of the request), so example.com/page1 should go to https://example.com/page1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

<IfModule mod_headers.c>
Header set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=10886400; includeSubDomains;"
</IfModule>
```

Only one redirect (http->https without www) and header only in this case

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm trying to understand.  The first condition would redirect any string containing "www.{string}" to https://{string}? and the second condition would redirect any non https to https?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly it